# Could the idiom 'belt and suspenders' be used to refer to a woman?

Tags: idioms, american-english

For example referring to an extremely cautious woman as a belt-and-suspenders kind of woman. Is it correct English (Am. English)?

Comment: It suggests something quite different to me.

Comment: @BarrieEngland  Yes, it manages to appeal to fetishists on both sides of the Atlantic.

Comment: 'Cautious' is not the first image that springs to mind, so maybe the metaphor isn't really working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that suspenders when worn by men are what are called braces in British English. Hence we have the expression *belt and braces*, applied to a course of action in which the participants wish to be doubly sure. Maybe this is what you have heard. It is not necesssarily applied to either a man or a woman.

Comment: In AE usage, however, *a belt-and-suspenders kind of guy* would be immediately understood and entirely idiomatic.

Comment: Barrie, while that is some nifty knowledge, this doesn't do anything towards OP's question. And OP had stated this was for American English, which StoneyB has kindly and correctly nudged that _belt-and-suspenders_ was correct for AmE. (I've only edited to supply the tag to make this even more clear.)

Comment: Oh...so the idea is that one is so cautious that one wears both a belt -and- suspenders (two different methods) to make sure one's pants do not fall down.

Comment: @Mitch: That's certainly the case with the British version.

Answer (score 2):

In days when suspenders (BE:braces) were standard attire for men, wearing both a belt and suspenders was a common expression for excessive caution: making assurance doubly sure, so to speak.

But women (except the young-and-hip, especially in the late 1970s, when Annie Hall* was popular) have rarely worn suspenders. And as the comments to the question tell you (and as you probably realized), the phrase suggests *garterbelt/suspender belt* when applied to a woman—only mildly salacious, perhaps, but Not Suitable For Work, as it may contribute to creating an actionably hostile work environment.

So what can you use instead? I don't know of an established catchphrase, but I offer this analogy as a stopgap:

*Belt and suspenders* suggests not "getting caught with your pants down". Once upon a time the feminine equivalent would have been "getting caught with your slip showing", but that's pretty obsolete by now. A more contemporary indiscretion is jocularly labeled a [*wardrobe malfunction*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wardrobe_malfunction).

So one who takes redundant measures to avoid such embarrassing exposure might be described as a [***tape-and-safety-pin***](http://www.ehow.com/info_12141056_bust-prom-dress-big-can-tailoring-it.html) kind of woman.

Comment: I don't get the suggestion. I've never heard the phrase before, and it is somewhat self-contradictory (it's strange to wear both a a belt and suspenders). Also, what does this have to do with 'suspicious'? Can you elaborate the connection and give any 'in the wild' examples that show your expected usage?

Comment: I've never heard the expression before either. I have a hard time conjuring a NSFW image that has to do with applying this phrase to a woman.  Also, I would have no idea what a tape-and-safety-pin kind of woman would be.  And "getting caught with your pants down" is not anywhere close to a "wardrobe malfunction" unless you interpret it literally.

Comment: Not only have I too not heard "belt and suspenders" (though I like it), I don't think "tape and safety pin" is an idiom at all. OP would have to make it one, and I don't think too-large strapless prom dresses resonate with enough people that it could be trusted to be understood by most people.

Comment: @Mitch  Gosh—am I that old? Wearing both a belt and suspenders used to be a very common expression to describe excessive caution: making assurance doubly sure, so to speak. As far as I know, it has nothing to with 'suspicious'.

Comment: @KitFox  Once upon a time garter belts or suspender belts had a distinct erotic significance. Of course I wouldn't know if that's still the case. As for t&sp, follow the link. One figurative wardrobe malfunction deserves another.

Comment: @JAM  It's not about just prom dresses, you know. Ask your wife or girlfriend. Last time I looked there were more women around than men, so I think it will resonate with 'most' people.

Comment: @StoneyB, I guess I could ask my husband or daughter...;)

Comment: @JAM Caught with my pants down! ... I was just trying to make up an alternative expression applicable to female attire, and I couldn't think of a doublet for hem weights.

Comment: @StoneyB: your given answer is far from the situation (there is no NSFW concerns about belt/suspenders for anybody, male or female. Your comment however -is- the answer. You should amend you answer to give it. (I don't know where I got 'suspicious' from; please ignore; I probably meant 'salacious').

Comment: @StoneyB: oh...so you made up the tape/safety pin thing? You should probably be more explicit about that so that ESL students won't think that people actually use it currently.